# Java: sun.sudio: Possible to not load audio file every time it is played?

Tags: java, audio

Is there any way to play the same audio file (Using sun.audio) without having to load the Fileinputstream every time? This is how I am trying to do it right now:

```
public static void nomnom() throws Exception
    {

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream ("nomnom.au");
        AudioStream as = new AudioStream (in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start (as);
        ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
    }
```

Despite "nomnom.au" being only a few seconds, I quickly get an OutofMemoryError when I repeat this method (to play the sound) about 30 times. I assume that this is caused by the fact that I am loading the audio file every time it needs to be played.

I have tried declaring the FileInputStream and AudioStream at the very beginning of my class, only loading my file once a the beginning of the main method:

```
public class Snake
{
static InputStream in; 
static AudioStream as; 
.
.
.
    public static void nomnomload () throws Exception
    {
    in = new FileInputStream ("nomnom.au"); 
    as = new AudioStream (in)
    }

    public static void nomnomplay() throws Exception
    {
    AudioPlayer.player.start (as);
    ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
    }
}
```

I was hoping to call the nomnomload method only at the beginning of my game. When I try to play the audio, however, I only get sound for the first time, and nothing for my following attempts to run nomnomplay.

Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data in a byte[] buffer.

For example you could modify your `load()` function as such

```
static byte[] buffer;
public static void nomnomload() throws Exception {
    if (buffer == null) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("nomnom.au");
        buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(buffer);
        fis.close();
    }
    in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
    as = new AudioStream(in);
}
```

Then you'd basically store your data once, in a defined array (you wouldn't be rereading a file, just an array)...